# batch request on google group api with oauth2-playground

Tags: batch-processing, google-groups-api, oauth2-playground

I'm trying to understand (and eventually make it work) batch request on the [google group API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-group-members#create_member).
With [Oauth2 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) I know how to perform a single request with:
on step 1 authorised API are
    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.member.readonly
    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.member
    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.readonly
    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group

on step 3 I'm making a post request with:
request URI:  [https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/***mytestgroup@domain.ext***/members](https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/mytestgroup@domain.ext/members)
and the body is:

> {
>         "email": "lya@example.com",
>          "role": "MEMBER"
>      }

So far so good, but now I'm trying to do the same in a batch request
I tried to follow the explanation here:
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/batch#example
but I didn't understood everything so I went there:
https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/batch

So I did the following request with, on step 1 the same API but on step 3:
a post request to:
https://www.googleapis.com/batch
with a custom content-type:
the header is now
    **multipart/mixed; boundary="batch_foobarbaz"**
and in the body request:

> --batch_foobarbaz
>      Content-Type: application/http
>      POST /admin/directory/v1/groups/***mytestgroup@domain.ext***/members HTTP/1.1
>
> Content-Type: application/json
>      content-length: 58
>      {
>         "email": "liz@example.com",
>          "role": "MEMBER"
>      }
>
> --batch_foobarbaz--

I also tried different variants but I never get to do the correct request, I systematically get *400 error*.
Can someone help me with that, I don't know what I can do to correct that.
Thanks in advance, Harold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey sorry for the inconvenience, I found my answer. Here is what I've done:

on step 1 authorised API are:
    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.member.readonly
    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.member
    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.readonly
    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group

on step 3 I'm making a post request with:
    https://www.googleapis.com/batch
    with a custom content-type: **`multipart/mixed; boundary="batch_foobarbaz"`**

body request:

> --batch_foobarbaz
>      Content-Type: application/http
>      Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
>
> POST /admin/directory/v1/groups/**mytestgroup@domain.ext**/members HTTP/1.1
>      Content-type: application/json
>
> {"email": "ldn@example.com", "role": "MEMBER"}
>      --batch_foobarbaz--

the important part here are the carriage return. They are mandatory after **Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary** and after **Content-type: application/json**